# Find the number of 'T'-s in a picture

Tags: image, image-processing

Given the following picture : [image]

How can I find the number of `T`'s in the picture ? 
I'm not after a matlab code , however I would appreciate for an algorithm or
some kind of an explanation how to approach the problem .

Regards

Comment: [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/101738/ocr-starting-point) post can be a great starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple template matching would probably do it. You simply cut out one of the Ts and then find the RMS error signal for each shift of the template (the T).

Pseudo code

```
for each x-position of T in image
    for each y-position of T in image
        err(x,y) = sqrt(sum(sum((T - image(x:x+Tsizex, y:y+Tsizey)).^2)))
    end end

ErrBinary = err < detectionThreshold
```

Now, each 1 in the errBinary is a detection. Depending on the resolution of the image, you might get a number of 1s in a cluster for each T in the image. One way to fix that could to iteratively pick a 1, and then clear all other ones in the neighbourhood. In this way you are actually defining a limit for how close Ts can be in order to be detected as two individual Ts.

**EDIT:**

Explanation of template comparison:

Basically what this method does, is to compare the reference template (a small image of a T in this case) to every possible location in the original image. For every location the error is calculated as a scalar RMS value of the difference if the two. So, the two for loops simply pick all possible sub images with a size of the template from the original image and use them to build an error surface. A small value in this surface will mean a good match between the template and sub image for that particular location. The location of the match in the original image corresponds to the location of the minimum in the error surface.

Regards

Comment: I didn't get you with the `for each x-position of T in image
` : what do you mean by that exactly , how can I know the position of the T ?

Comment: Added an explanation to answer